# Different programming languages integration in JHipster microservices web app

Tags: c#, angular, microservices, jhipster, gateway

I have an existing **JHipster** microservices web app with **Angular** frontend and **Consul** service discovery.

I have created a **gateway** and one microservice with Java, Spring, and Hibernate. Everything works fine.

**WHAT I WANT**

I want to add one more microservice with a different programming language, such as **.Net** and **C#**

**QUESTION**

Is it possible? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible as long as your other services are able to integrate into your existing infra structure:

- by registering in Consul and reading their configuration from Consul too
- validating gateway's authentication token
- forwarding their logs to your centralized logging system (e.g ELK)
- exposing their metrics to your monitoring system (e.g. Prometheus)

As JHipster uses quite common technologies, it should not be too hard.

Comment: The third and fourth points seem to be a little bit tricky. Let's say I should send these logs and metrics to the gateway? Sorry, I'm still a newbie to this. Thank you!

Comment: Not really, JHipster has you covered on this, check the docs. I suppose it's a project for learning not really for production, so you should try to use your JHipster generated infra structure to its full extent with  logs and metrics before integrating non-java stacks.

Comment: I'll check the docs and then give it a shot. Thank you very much!